# how do I run after replacing url

Tags: javascript, jquery

so this is my code, in order to run this `mailTab.$('#username').val(username);` , i have to first wait for `mailTab.window.location.href = mailTab.window.location.href.replace("step=4", "step=3")` to finish loading, so question is how/where should I put this code? `mailTab.$('#username').val(username);`

```
<script>
window.onload = _ => {
    $(`#certform input[type='submit']`).click(_ => {
        const username = $(`#certform input[name='username']`).val();
        alert(username);
        const mailTab = window.open(`admin/index.php?module=user-mass_mail&action=resend&mid=21`);

        mailTab.onload = _ => {
            mailTab.window.location.href = mailTab.window.location.href.replace("step=4", "step=3")



        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Changing `location.href` triggers a page loading. After that you wouldn't be able to use the variable `username` anyway. Why do you want to change `href`?

Comment: using the variable works after changing location.href, tried using setinterval but it didn’t work like what i expected.. when i use window.open, it will automatically generate a new link with step=4 and in order to edit the username i have to go to step=3

Comment: You may be reloading the variable in the new page, because variables shouldn't persevere through page loads. So you have no control on the backend?